# Is Loopback 4 production ready?

Tags: loopbackjs

I think I read all the documentation and I'm still confused on wether LB4 is ready for production use?
As I understand, it still misses Many-to-Many relationship and some OpenApi specs implementation. The documentation is very scarce so it left me very confused.

We are currently searching for good node REST solution and LB4 looks very promising with things like TS and dep. injection(more modular design), but it looks like we'll have to skip this one for now. Is anyone using this at all? I would be very glad to hear some experiences.

Answer (score 2):

We have used it for one of our application. I agree that there are some gaps but for most of the stuff, you can handle it pretty well in loopback 4. The most significant reason for that is the awesome extensibility of LB4. That's the reason why we could do authentication, authorization, bpm integration, etc. in our application by creating Components in LB4.

After we were done with it, we thought about sharing our experience with open source world. So, we published a loopback 4 starter application which demonstrates a multi-tenant architecture, supports authentication via passport strategies (using [loopback4-authentication](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-authentication) extension we created), supports simple permission keys based authorization (using [loopback4-authorization](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-authorization) extension we created), soft delete entity (using [loopback4-soft-delete extension](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-soft-delete) we created) and DB revisioning, upgrades (using [db-migrate](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package).

Hope it helps clear your doubts about loopback 4. Trust me, its an awesome framework with lots of futuristic goals.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing many things about LB due to poor docs. We eventually picked NestJS which is very modular, also written in TS, with DI and has much better documentation and examples/techniques.